# Redirect to different pages depending on input is email or phone number

Tags: php, html, web

What I want to do is if user put their phone number it redirect to page1 otherwise(put their email) it go to page2.

```
<form action="file.php" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="code" />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
```

file.php (php only works if all number are in order)

```
switch($_POST['code']):
case '0123456789':
    header('Location: page1.html');
break;
default:
    header('Location: page2.html'); endswitch;
```

I'd be glad to hear your suggestion

Please bear with me as I am yet a fledgling in this field

Comment: If I were doing it, I'd check to see whether the input is a valid email address, perhaps using `filter_var()`, if it is I'd redirect to the appropriate page, otherwise go for it being a phone number. Either way is fallible - what happens if the user puts the area code in parentheses, or inserts dashes to separate parts? The safest way is a checkbox, or two input fields and decide based on which one they fill in.

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification.

Comment: Show 2 inputs? One for phone, one for email. Depending on which one is filled redirect. And if both are filled show an error or choose one of the 2 yourself.

Answer (score 0):

PHP doesn't pattern match like that.  I think you're looking for something a bit more like this:

```
if (!empty($_POST['code'])) {

  if (preg_match('/^[0-9]+$/', trim($_POST['code']))) {
    header('Location: page1.html');
    exit;
  }

  header('Location: page2.html');
  exit;
}
```

As @dropsnoot suggests above, you'll need to finesse that regular expression if you want to allow spaces, brackets, dashes etc in the telephone number entry